# How to pick coloured balls from a bag where you aren't aware about the number of each coloured ball under these limited conditions?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A bag contains 17 balls of 4 different colours. There exists minimum of 2 balls of a particular colour in the bag. Bag contains maximum number of green balls and the number of balls of any two colours aren't the same. If we randomly pick 11 balls from the bag such that there should be at least two balls of the same colour and the remaining balls of another colour. Then the probability of having at least one green ball among those 11 balls picked from the bag?

By basic trial and error, we can say, the balls of each colour in the bag can be, (2,3,4,8), (2,3,5,7) and (2,4,5,6) where the highest numbers represent green and the other three numbers can represent any of the three colours. So, total number of bags with different colour arrangements within them would be $(3!)3=18$. The probability of occurenece of each of the bags is $\frac{1}{18}$.

Now, let's take one case of the bags of the type (2,3,4,8). The probability for them would be:

$$\frac{1}{18}\left(\frac{\binom{8}{8}\binom{3}{3}+\binom{8}{7}\binom{4}{4}+\binom{8}{8}\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{17}{11}}\right)$$

If we multiply this with 6 (number of ways in which the 3 times occurring and 4 times occurring balls can be chosen then we get the total probability for the bags of the type (2,3,4,8):

$$\frac{6}{18}\left(\frac{\binom{8}{8}\binom{3}{3}+\binom{8}{7}\binom{4}{4}+\binom{8}{8}\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{17}{11}}\right)$$

Similarly, we can say for the bags of the type  (2,3,5,7):

$$\frac{2}{18}\left(\frac{\binom{7}{7}\binom{5}{4}+\binom{7}{6}\binom{5}{5}}{\binom{17}{11}}\right)$$

And for the bags of type (2,4,5,6):

$$\frac{1}{18}\left(\frac{\binom{6}{6}\binom{5}{5}}{\binom{17}{11}}\right)$$

Adding them all up gives a vastly different result from the answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is the given answer?

Comment: tldr, have you used bayes' theorem or not?

Comment: @DS the given answer is $\frac{17}{97}$

Comment: @DS  (3,4,5,6) has 18 balls while the question asks one to stick to 17 balls

Comment: oh right. The 18 in the denominator of your answer messed up my mind

Comment: @DS I dont think I have used Bayes' theorem here. I MIGHT have applied it but I am not good with keeping track of these names. I have written down my approach, you can see for yourself

Comment: How did you interpret "at least two balls of the same colour and the remaining balls of another colour"?

Comment: @DS You just have to pick 2 balls from the 4 with 2 ball of any colour being the minimum. I think I see a few mistakes I made there

Comment: I think I've figured out your mistake. Let $A = \{\text{Atleast one of the 11 is green}\}$ and $B = \{\text{at least two balls of the same colour and the remaining balls of another colour}\}$. You are required to find $P(A|B)$, but you have instead found $P(A \cap B)$.